# Process still runs after going out of scope - Is that safe?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Given the code below, [which was an accepted answer to another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728102/2549384)

Is this safe to run new Processes this way or should I manage a reference to MyProcess?

It is my understanding the GC will (eventually) dispose of objects which no longer have a reference. With MyProcess going out of scope, wouldn't the Dispose() method be invoked when this reference is eventually Garbage Collected?
My impression would be that it may run for a while, up until the GC does a collection.

```
void TestMethod()
{
    Process MyProcess = new Process();
    MyProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("app.exe");
    MyProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
    MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "some arguments";
    MyProcess.Start();
}
```

Comment: I assume the reference to the process, via MyProcess will be garbage collected. However, the process itself will still continue to run.

Comment: A process never "goes out of scope" - once you start a process, it runs (as a separate process) until it ends or someone forcibly terminates it. A `Process` instance may go out of scope but that's not the process itself - it's just a descriptor of the process that lets you get information about a particular process.

Comment: But wouldn't the Dispose() method be called and end the process?

Comment: @Don No, `Dispose` gets rid of the resources associated with the in-memory `Process` instance, not the process _described by that instance_.

Comment: @Don Look at it this way: your `Process` instance lives independently of the process - you create it before the process even gets started. Once it's started, it lives in a separate memory space. The `Process` instance has the ability to get updated information about the process as long as the instance is in scope - after that it gets cleaned up but that doesn't affect the process.

Comment: So would it be safe to put a MyProcess.Dispose(); immediately after Start() is called?

Comment: @Don If you don't care about the process after you start it, yes (use a `using` block instead). If you care about it then you need to use a higher-level scope to keep the `Process` instance around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you start a process, it never goes out of scope - a process gets its own memory space and its own time slices from the operating system and it runs until it decides to quit or someone forcibly terminates it.

A [`Process`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3pp-Hg-7JAhWKOiYKHZfJDFQQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.diagnostics.process(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHyJTeMmWmlsxb2cGqQ6oTELQiQ6A) instance is a descriptor for a particular process - it's not the process itself but it has the ability to get information about the process and to make certain changes to the process.

The `Process` instance can be disposed of - this releases the resources needed to query the operating system process but it doesn't actually end the process in question - it just stops the `Process` instance from being used to access the underlying process anymore.

If you want to use the `Process` instance to actually stop the underlying process, you can call `Kill()` but this is dangerous and not recommended - this literally stops the process right away, without letting the process to shut down gracefully (which can lead to all kinds of problems).

To answer your question: there's nothing wrong with the code in your question - it simply starts an operating system process and then throws away the `Process` instance without using it for anything else. (It'd be possible to use the `Process` instance to redirect the standard input / output, wait for the process to finish, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The `Process` object is independent of the actual operating system process. Either one can terminate while the other lives on.

If the `Process` object dies then the operating system process can continue. You just can't interact with it through the now deceased `Process` object.

If the operating process terminates, then the `Process` object is still meaningful. For instance, you can query the exit code.

The code in the question is perfectly safe.